# Map different column values with website context

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({   
    "index": ["EXEC sp_delete_job",  "exec sp_add_job", "something else","exec sp_add_jobserver"],
    "index1": ["NaN",  "NaN",  "NaN", "exec sp_delete_job"],
    "index2": ["EXEC sp_droplogin",  "EXEC sp_delete_job",  "NaN", "something else"],
    "index3": ["EXEC sp_droplogin",  "EXEC sp_delete_job",  "exec sp_add_job", "exec sp_delete_job"]
})
df1.head()

      index                 index1                  index2          index3
0   EXEC sp_delete_job       NaN                EXEC sp_droplogin   EXEC sp_droplogin
1   exec sp_add_job          NaN                EXEC sp_delete_job  EXEC sp_delete_job
2   something else           NaN                  NaN                   exec sp_add_job
3   exec sp_add_jobserver    exec sp_delete_job   something else    exec sp_delete_job
```

What I want is to map the columns values with their description from this site
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/system-stored-procedures-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

So for example this value `EXEC sp_droplogin` can be mapped with the description from here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-droplogin-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

so the output will look like this:

```
    index
    0   Removes a SQL Server login. This prevents access to an instance of SQL Server under 
 that login name.
    1   EXEC sp_delete_job
    2   exec sp_add_job
    3   exec sp_delete_job
    4   exec sp_add_jobserver
```

And the same must be done with the other column values.

What is the best way to perform this? With BeautifulSoup?

Can you provide some ideas/direction/code etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call a function for each `index` entry and replace it with the results of a `requests` `beautifulsoup` lookup:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def description(value):   
    name = value.split(' ')[1].replace('_', '-')
    url = f"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/{name}-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15"
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
    div = soup.find('div', class_="content")
    return [p.text for p in div.find_all('p')][3]


df = pd.DataFrame({   
    "index": ["EXEC sp_droplogin",  "EXEC sp_delete_job",  "exec sp_add_job", "exec sp_delete_job","exec sp_add_jobserver"],
})


df['index'] = df['index'].map(description)
print(df)
```

This would change your dataframe as follows:

```
                                                                                                  index
0  Removes a SQL Server login. This prevents access to an instance of SQL Server under that login name.
1                                                                                        Deletes a job.
2                                                     Adds a new job executed by the SQL Agent service.
3                                                                                        Deletes a job.
4                                                    Targets the specified job at the specified server.
```

1. First take `value` e.g. `EXEC sp_droplogin` and split it on the space. Then take the second part `sp_droplogin` and replace any `_` with `-` which is needed for the URL.
2. Create a suitable URL based on `name`.
3. Use `requests.get()` to obtain the corresponding HTML from the Microsoft site.
4. Locate a `<div class='content'>` which holds the description.
5. Inside that div, locate all the `<p>` elements and extract the text for each. The fourth entry holds the required text. Return that.

If there are `None` values, you would need to test for this and return a suitable value:

```py
def description(value):
    if value:
        .........existing code......
    else:
        return "Not found"
```

---

For your updated example, I suggest you use a dictionary to keep the results of each request to avoid looking up the same value multiple times.

You can use `.applymap()` to run the function for all items in the dataframe.

Lastly, if `value` does not start with `exec`  then just return the value unchanged (or whatever you prefer)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

procedures = {}     # cache of results

def description(value):   
    if value.lower().startswith("exec "):
        name = value.lower().split(' ')[1].replace('_', '-')
        
        if name in procedures:  # already seen?
            return procedures[name]
        else:
            url = f"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/{name}-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15"
            req = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
            div = soup.find('div', class_="content")
            text = [p.text for p in div.find_all('p')][3]
            procedures[name] = text
            return text
    else:
        return value


df = pd.DataFrame({   
    "index": ["EXEC sp_delete_job",  "exec sp_add_job", "something else", "exec sp_add_jobserver"],
    "index1": ["NaN", "NaN",  "NaN", "exec sp_delete_job"],
    "index2": ["EXEC sp_droplogin", "EXEC sp_delete_job", "NaN", "something else"],
    "index3": ["EXEC sp_droplogin", "EXEC sp_delete_job", "exec sp_add_job", "exec sp_delete_job"]
})

df = df.applymap(description)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Can you explain the code please? More specifically I want to understand this line "name = value.split(' ')[1].replace('_', '-')"
and also this line "return [p.text for p in div.find_all('p')][3]". Also does this code works in the case of None or NaN values? How the [1] and [3] work in the code?

Comment: I have added an explanation to the answer, hope this helps

Comment: yes thank you it helps. I update my dataframe to reflect the true shape of my original dataframe. There I have also values that are not much with any value from the Microsoft site. If you can update you code would be wonderful. In any case I accept the current answer. Thank you again.